# Mule - data weave throwing error during munit test, error is There are two transformers that are an exact match for input

Tags: maven, mule, mule-studio, dataweave, munit

The transformation (xml to json) works completely fine during normal run, but when the same flow is being tested using MUnit it fails at dataweave with error message

> There are two transformers that are an exact match for input: interface org.mule.api.transport.OutputHandler, output: class java.lang.String.
>   Transformers are: ObjectToAtomString(class org.mule.transformer.simple.ObjectToString) and ObjectToString(class org.mule.transformer.simple.ObjectToString$$EnhancerByMUNIT$$99111c4f)

I have added the input MIME TYPE in data transformation as well.

I tried to check the tranformation in another demo project to test it using munit and it passed dataweave successfully without any error.

I have data mapper 3.7.3 jar included in the project and pom file.

Comment: Does your object-to-string transformer's have a name attribute? Where are they? Is one in your flow under test and the other in munit?

Comment: There is no object-to-string transformer in the flow or munit. The error comes at Dataweave which is transforming the XML to Json. The error looks like there are 2 transformation but there is no such thing in the flow. Can it be a issue with classpath?

Answer (score 0):

We faced similar issue with DataWeave in Mule 3.8.2 version for munit, though normal run was working fine. we resolved it with below workaround:
We had Byte Array to String transformer which was throwing this exception. We changed it to Byte Array to Object and in the object we gave class as java.lang.String.

Comment: In my case, I am not using byte array to Strimg transformation. I am only using dataweave which is throwing the same exception mentioned above.

Comment: can you share your flow xml file to debug the issue.

Comment: I have checked the flow in another demo project and its working fine with MUNIT. So, my guess is the issue with classpath or libraries.

Comment: good, can u share which libraries were missing for the benefit of all?

Comment: The issue is not resolved yet, still looking into it. The same flow works in another project, I only took the subflow and tested it in another project, the munit tests it fine. but my complete project still throwing the same exception.

Comment: Please check if below link helps: https://www.ricston.com/blog/weaveoutputhandler-and-transformers/